# How to set default text for addTextField in UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uialertcontroller

Below is the the code I tried. textField.placeholder works perfectly, I need to set default text for textfield created using addTextField in UIAlertController.

```
      let getPinNameAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
      getPinNameAlert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) -> Void in
      // textField.placeholder = "Pin Name"
      textField.text = "Current Pin Name"
      textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
      textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
    })
```

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt to set the placeholder. Are you saying that the line `textField.text = "Current Pin Name"` doesn't actually set the text of the text field?

Comment: @rmaddy that's right. textField.text = "Current Pin Name" is returning blank when textField is prompted. I removed the placeholder line from my code as that's working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "return blank when textField is prompted"?

Comment: no text displayed. just textField ready to type new text.

Comment: I can confirm it is blank

Comment: that's right @JohnDoe. Is there anyway I can set the text?

Comment: Remove the line `textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true`.  By default, it automatically focuses on the text field, that is why it is being cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true`

By default, the alert automatically focuses on the text field, that is why the text you set is being cleared.